# How can I plot this Octave\Matlab function output?

Tags: matlab, math, octave, matlab-figure, linear-algebra

I everyone,
I am pretty new in Octave\MatLab and I have the following doubt. I have this code calculating a sigmoid function for a parameter z:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
%SIGMOID Compute sigmoid function
%   g = SIGMOID(z) computes the sigmoid of z.

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
g = zeros(size(z));

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: Compute the sigmoid of each value of z (z can be a matrix,
%               vector or scalar).

g = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-z));

% =============================================================

end
```

z could be a scalar, a vector or a matrix.

For example doing something like this:

```
>> X = [1 2; 0 5]
X =

   1   2
   0   5

>> g = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-X));
>> g
g =

   0.73106   0.88080
   0.50000   0.99331
```

Given the matrix X having 2 features X1 and X2 (the 2 column) how can I plot this function? The output is a three dimensional function?

Comment: Are you using Octave or MATLAB? Please tag only one of the two, not both. They are similar, but not the same, and differences are significant enough that you could get different answers depending on which of the two you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

The output is not a 3D function because you have one input `X`, and one output `g`, it's 2D.

You can display it **column by column** , displaying each column as a separate function on the same plot:

```
plot(X, g)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
figure
hold on
for i = 1:size(X,2)
    plot(X(:,i), g(:,i))
end
hold off
```

You can display it **row by row**, displaying each row as a separate function on the same plot:

```
plot(X', g')
```

which is equivalent to:

```
figure
hold on
for i = 1:size(X,1)
    plot(X(i,:), g(i,:))
end
hold off
```

You can display it as an **array**:

```
plot(X(:), g(:))
```